# How to apply function on text selected in visual block

Tags: vim

I often manipulate ascii files containing mac addresses in this format : `DEADBEEFDEADBEEF` and often have to transform it in this format `de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef`. Most of the time i have a sed expression to do this automatically when processing well defined files, but it happens i have to go and do it manually so i did this function :

```
function ConvertMac() range
    s/\v(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\L\1:\L\2:\L\3:\L\4:\L\5:\L\6:\L\7:\L\8/g
endfunction
```

This works only if the file has all mac addresses in a column organized file, with the mac in the first column. I would like to make it work when i select a visual block in any column, or even mac addresses on different columns.

Full example :

we have the following file that consist of 4 column in which i would like to change the 3rd column to the format i mentioned earlier :

```
1    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 1
2    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 2
3    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 3
4    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 4
5    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 5
6    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 6
7    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 7
8    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 8
9    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 9
10   DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 10
11   DEADBEEFDEADBABE   DEADBEEFDEADBEEF 11
```

With the above vim function, selecting the 3rd column in Visual Block mode and calling the command `'<,'>call ConvertMac()`, this will yield :

```
1 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 1
2 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 2
3 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 3
4 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 4
5 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 5
6 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 6
7 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 7
8 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 8
9 :  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 9
10:  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 10
11:  : d:ea:db:ee:fd:eadb:ab:e :  :de:ad:be:efDEADBEEF 11
```

The problem here is it is not taking the visual block selection into account, and is matching even the first characters in the pattern space.

What i would like instead is have only the visual block selection taken into account in the pattern space so the result would be :

```
1    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 1
2    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 2
3    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 3
4    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 4
5    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 5
6    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 6
7    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 7
8    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 8
9    DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 9
10   DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 10
11   DEADBEEFDEADBABE   de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef 11
```

Comment: Could you add realistic before/after samples to your question?

Comment: Added exemple of expected and obtained behaviors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found after a little digging, to substitute in visual selection, one has to provide '\%V' flag :

```
function ConvertMac() range
    '<,'>s/\%V\v(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\L\1:\L\2:\L\3:\L\4:\L\5:\L\6:\L\7:\L\8/g
endfunction
```

This works